# Lua: check local or global variable

Tags: variables, lua

Is there a way to check if variable is global or local? I mean to do it using programming facilities, not by reading a code?
For example

```
print(type(a))=>"number", 
print(checklocal(a))=>true
```

Comment: The problem is that global and local are not mutually exclusive.  A variable with name `a` could exist at both local and global scope at the same time (although the local instance would shadow the global one).

Comment: Why do you need this? What problem are you really trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Variables are local in certain scope. Yes, you can access the local variables of any active function by calling `debug.getlocal(StackLevel, Index)`, it returns two values:

1. Name of the variable
2. Value of the variable

   ```
    -- Example 
    local isGlobal = 99
    function testFunc(var)
        local v1, v2, v3 = 1, 2, 3
        local a = 1
        while true do
            local name, value = debug.getlocal(1, a)
            if not name then break end
            print(name, value)
            a = a + 1
        end
   end

   testFunc('xyz')
   -- Result
   --   var    xyz
   --   v1     1
   --   v2     2
   --   v3     3
   --   a      5
   ```

`local isGlobal = 99` is outside of the scope of our `testFunc()` hence getlocal will not print it, whereas all other variables within scope of our testFunc are printed with their values.

Answer (score 1):

The locality of any given variable can be always determined from the source, so if you program in pure Lua, I can't see any purpose of this. I suppose it might be useful in cases where you do some preprocessing perhaps, so here is one way of doing it, without having to depend on the name:

```
local variable
print(debug.getupvalue(function()variable()end, 1) ~= "_ENV")
```

`function()variable()end` will, for a local variable, capture it as an upvalue (`debug.getupvalue` will return `"variable"`). If `variable` gets resolved to a global variable instead, the function has to store the global environment, `_ENV`, as an upvalue instead (which gets indexed with the name of the variable). There is no need to call `variable` in the function, this is just the shortest way to "use" it. If `variable` is `_ENV`, it always prints `false` (even though `_ENV` is always local).

Another option, which works correctly for `_ENV`:

```
local variable
print(debug.getupvalue(function()_ENV(variable)end, 2) ~= nil)
```

`function()_ENV(variable)end` always captures `_ENV`, and `variable` as well, if it is local, so checking the second index determines whether the variable was local or not.

This works from Lua 5.2 onwards.

For a solution without using the debug library, you can temporarily set the `__newindex` metamethod on `_ENV`, assign some values around, and check if the metamethod gets called.